# Finishing basement- why did contractor drop ceiling so low?

Tags: basement, framing, ceiling

Finishing a basement and adding a bathroom. Basement had low ceilings to begin (about 6’9” under the ducts and pipes in the future shower area shower). I thought they would drop by at most an inch with drywall work around these protrusions.

Contractor added many 2x4’s to drop the ceiling. It seems to me that the ones on this image that I marked in green might not be necessary? (But what do I know..).  The red circle is the future shower area and the area of most concern for ceiling height. Clearly the height under the ducts near the front or this pic will drop lower than the shower area and I’m ok with that.

[image]

Any advice on whether the green marked 2x4’s are absolutely necessary? I’m going to talk to him on Monday but wanted to be prepared. TIA.

Comment: It looks to me like there's a bracket or hanger of some kind supporting a duct at the top of the pic while drops below the level where the tops of those green-highlighted 2x4s are.

Comment: It looks like the objective was to create a level ceiling that clears all obstructions.  It looks like the shower ceiling could be raised three inches and attached directly to the joists.  You could decorate it to look intentional, like a tray ceiling.  Without the requirement from you the builder would not just do that.